# terminal shortcut doesn't work after upgrading python to 3.74

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 16.04; after upgrading my python from 3.5 to 3.74, the terminal doesn't show up using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Reverting the default python to be 3.5 makes the shortcut work.

Is there any possibility to make the shortcut work with python 3.74 as well?

Comment: could you elaborate? what terminal are you talking about? where do you set the shortcuts? is package responsible for the terminal invocation installed under python 3.74?

Comment: @Bart I haven't placed any shortcut yet, used the default one. The package has been downloaded from python.com website and compiled. I don't know of the terminal only use python 3 or something else

Comment: presumably whatever's responsible for shortcuts, under new python, lost them. you may have to readd the shortcuts, check at `System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"`.

Comment: also, what terminal are you using? what is the window manager?

Comment: @Bart I use Gnome terminal

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved. The main reason was that when I tried to compile the python 3.7.4 on my laptop, I had set the installation destination to be `/usr/local` rather `/usr`. Recompiled and installed with the second address and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably whatever's responsible for shortcuts, under new python, lost them.

To fix this:

1. First disable the existing command/key combination with the command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal ""
   ```

   Which will make <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> "available" again for another command.
2. Now open keyboard settings: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=<profilename>
   ```

   to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, where `<profilename>` is the name of your profile, most likely `Default`

Comment: doesn't work :(